# Why can't I dereference a pointer to multidimensional array?

Tags: c

Basic question.. had to ask. Any help will be appreciated.

Q: Why can't I dereference the pointer to a multidimensional array like this:

```
int arr [2][2] = { {1, 2} , {3, 4} };

printf("%d ", *arr);
```

Comment: In general, you should include details of what's going wrong (error message, expected and actual output, etc.).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* dereference it, it is just that the result is not going to be what you'd expect: `*arr` is not an `int`, it's a *pointer to an `int`* (OK, a one-dimensional array). If you want to see `1` printed, add another star:

```
printf("%d ", **arr);
```

Comment: `*arr` is actually a 1-dimensional array which decays to a pointer to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

If `a` is `int[][]` then `*a` is `int[]`. You need another level of redirection to access an array element. That is, `**a` is `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
int arr [2][2] = { {1, 2} , {3, 4} };

printf("%d ", **arr);
```

You need two levels of dereferencing, as your array is two-dimensional.

Comment: Why not just use an index anyway? `printf("%d ", arr[0][0])`

Comment: @detly That's definitively a way - the question was specifically about the pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Remember if we define a as int[][], then it means it is a two dimensional array and it can be dereferenced by **a. If array is one dimensional then we should use *a to dereference it...

Try it..